# error: incompatible types: U cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, generics

I have the following program.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {


    public static <U extends Number> double median(List<U> l) {

        double Q = 0;

        int n = l.size();
        if (n%2 == 0) {
            Q = ((int)l.get(n/2) + (int)l.get(n/2-1)) / (double)2;
        } else {
            Q = new Double((int)l.get(n/2));
        }

        return Q;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            l.add(sc.nextInt());
        }

        Collections.sort(l);

        double Q1 = 0, Q2 = 0, Q3 = 0;

        List<Integer> lower = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> upper = new ArrayList<>();

        if (n%2 == 0) {
            lower.addAll(l.subList(0, n/2));
            upper.addAll(l.subList(n/2, n));
        } else {
            lower.addAll(l.subList(0, n/2));
            upper.addAll(l.subList(n/2 + 1, n));
        }

        Q2 = median(l);
        Q1 = median(lower);
        Q3 = median(upper);

        System.out.format("%.0f%n", Q1);
        System.out.format("%.0f%n", Q2);
        System.out.format("%.0f%n", Q3);

        sc.close();

    }
}
```

It compiles fine and runs on my local machine, when I try to run it from eclipse, but when I submit it to hackerrank, I get the following compilation error.

```
Solution.java:12: error: incompatible types: U cannot be converted to int
            Q = ((int)l.get(n/2) + (int)l.get(n/2-1)) / (double)2;
                           ^
  where U is a type-variable:
    U extends Number declared in method <U>median(List<U>)
Solution.java:12: error: incompatible types: U cannot be converted to int
            Q = ((int)l.get(n/2) + (int)l.get(n/2-1)) / (double)2;
                                             ^
  where U is a type-variable:
    U extends Number declared in method <U>median(List<U>)
Solution.java:14: error: incompatible types: U cannot be converted to int
            Q = new Double((int)l.get(n/2));
                                     ^
  where U is a type-variable:
    U extends Number declared in method <U>median(List<U>)
3 errors
```

I don't even understand why I have to cast each list element back to an int, I thought since U extends Number, I should be able to add list elements without casting back to ints. Is there something I'm not understanding about generics? Q1, Q2, Q3 are guaranteed to be integers (but thats just because of the input test cases), but that shouldn't matter, why isn't my program compiling?

Comment: Well `U extends Number`, so `List<U>` could be a `List<Integer>` as you are using it. But it could also be a `List<Double>`, or a `List<BigInteger>`, etc... What if you passed a `List<Long>` or a `List<Atomic integer>` to the method? Why even apply generics here? Seems forced

Comment: so I can't use the same method to find the median of a list of doubles, or floats, or BigIntegers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the `intValue()` method on the `Number` elements instead of cast them to int.

( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue-- )

Comment: Can't I use this method to find the median of a list of floats, or doubles?

Comment: yes, it will work also on a list of floats or doubles, but the numbers will be rounded. If you want to return the median as a double then is better use `doubleValue()` method, so you won't loose precision if the list contains floating point numbers. On the other hand a list of Integer or Long containing big numbers will loose precision casting them to double.

Answer (score 0):

Why you declaring the median method as generic if you anyway casting the list items to integer?

Change it to `public static double median(List<Integer> l)` and remove all the casting to int.

Comment: okay fine, I won't cast to int, but it should work right? I should be able to find the median, even for a list of doubles. or floats, or any other data type. If I remove the (int) castings, the code won't compile. Because it can't add elements of type U

Comment: You can do l.get(i).doubleValue() instead of casting.